# Me and my Brother, the runners

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I run around my friends, I am not that wide, but very long,
Some are behind me, but all are within my brother. Some of the young ones run with me, but they don't really count. It's cold out here, but even worse for my brother.I look grey and dull, but I can go quite fast, even though I'm dusty and full of ice.

Who am I, and who is my brother?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And another try.. I love this puzzle :D
Are you

> The asteroid belt?

Then your brother would be:

> Kuiper belt

Explanation:

> The asteroid belt lies between the orbits of Mars and Jupiter, it contains numerous irregularly shaped bodies called asteroids. Kuiper belt is similar to the asteroid belt, and it is located in the outer Solar System, more or less putting everything else in the system inside of its orbit. It is also discovered that there is a population of comets inside the asteroid belt, that are made of ice and dust.

Comment: Yay! You finally did it! Well done!

Answer (score 4):

I would say that you are a

> comet

because

> Comets orbit the sun. Comets are small in diameter but have long 'tails' when moving close to stars which heat them up. They travel in outer space, where it is very cold. Since comets often have ice and small rocks, they should not be extremely bright.

I would also guess that your brother is

> a comet's tail

since

> The dust behind a comet belongs inside the comet's tail.

Comment: Good idea, very close, but now the right answer

Comment: @RohitJose Is it the second part that is wrong? Or is telling me too much of a hint?

Comment: The theme of it is very close

Answer (score 2):

You are

> Hyperion (Saturn's moon)

Your brother is

> Lapetus (another moon of Saturn)

I run around my friends,

> Hyperion is orbiting around Saturn and there are other moons and particles inside his orbit.

I am not that wide, but very long,

> Hyperion is an irregular shape moon.

Some are behind me, but all are within my brother.

> There are other moons and particles that are behind Hyperion's orbit, but Lapetus is by far the most distant of Saturn's large moons (so others are inside its orbit).

Some of the young ones run with me, but they don't really count. It's cold out here, but even worse for my brother.

> It's cold in space. It's worse for Lapetus because he is deeper into space, on a bigger distance from Saturn.

I look grey and dull, but I can go quite fast, even though I'm dusty and full of ice.

> Hyperion is composed largely of water ice with a small amount of rock

Answer (score 1):

Or it could be

> Uranus

and its brother

> Neptun

Explanation:

> They are known as "ice giants". Their friends (other planets) run inside their orbits. Many inside the orbit of Uranus, but all inside the orbit of Neptun. "Some of the young ones run with me" would refer to the moons of Uranus. And because Neptun is the furthest planet from the Sun it is colder for him than for the others.

Comment: Well done, but 1848's guess about comets is still closer than yours. You're close though.